# Same session is used in rails 2.3.2 App before and after login to the App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

We build a rails 2.3.2 app and has login/logout mechanism using rails session/cookies to log in (not using device gem).

After log out, we are resetting the session by using rails **reset_session** which will drop the session data and create a new session. Created session will be available in a browser (cookies[_session_id]) and after successful login (username-password), the same session is used in the application.

Question

1. Why is session same before and after login?
2. How to create a new session after a successful login?

I don't want to build this by using device gem or any other gem.

Attached screenshot, please check and give me solutions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `reset_session` has exactly that behavior in later versions of rails. It invalidates the session identifier - and sends a new cookie. Rails 2 is really ancient and has several security vulnerabilities - chances are that upgrading will fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks Max for the reply, Do we have any other way to fix this issue? Because this is 'Improper session management' vulnerability in our app. Our app is a monolithic app (Big App) so difficult to upgrade rails.

Comment: You would have to debug why `reset_session` is not working in the first place. However if this is a security review your app most likely will not pass anyways. Doing further development on an app that is slipping that far behind may be wasted money and effort.

Comment: After log out, I am calling 'reset_session' which is destroying session and creating a new session. But I want to create a new session after successful login, not before login. I spent 2 days on debugging but i didn't get solid solutions.

Comment: And how do you suppose we will be able to help you with no relevant example?