# Pre-post login session id is not changing in rails 2.3.2 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

We build a rails 2.3.2 app and has login/logout mechanism using active_record_store to store the session.

```
Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 2.3.2
Server : Apache (Passenger 4.0.59)

config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
```

Once a user clicks on log out button, we are destroying the session by using rails reset_session function which will drop and create a new session. After successful log out a user will redirect to login page with created session. Again a user login using username-password then user information will store in created session.

**Question?**

**How to reset session after successful login (username-password) and store user info into new session?**
I want to fix this without device gem.

I tried by executing reset_session function but it is a just empty hash.

```
def login
    p  session.session_id #7bb32e02c4495b192b233089b0d586c7
    reset_session
    p session # {}
    p  session.session_id # nil
    a = authenticate(username, password)
    session[:app_id] = a.id
  end

  def logout
    #old session
    #5a4c229eba44d63058c50a23b104d6f6b6b981bb
    reset_session 
    # new session
    #7bb32e02c4495b192b233089b0d586c7
    redirect_to_login
  end
```

**This is an improper session management VAPT issue (Security issue).**

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Perhaps it is just me, but your question is not clear to me. What exactly to you try to achieve? What doesn't work? How is that related to your code examples? Apart from that I would argue that your biggest security issue is using a Rails version that is more than seven years old and that has many known security issues.

Comment: I want to create a new session after successful authentication. Ya i know we are using old rails app (enterprise app) but for us, it is difficult to update the rails version (3+ or 5).

Comment: The same thing asked in another StackOverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107700/same-session-is-used-in-rails-2-3-2-app-before-and-after-login-to-the-app but didn't get the solution.